# Possible to let browser clients "own" a sqlite file on the server?

Tags: python, sqlite, telethon

Scenario: Web app allows users to login to telegram >> ".session" sqlite file is created in server once logged in

Problem: I now have full access to N number of users' telegram account

Question: Is there a way for me(developer) to have no access to their session file whilst they(browser client) have full access to it during their session?

note: I still need to use their session file to get specific messages when they do a http request to the endpoint(s). but i dont have to see this data, only they have to.

Comment: i don't  think removing your access is the best way to solve this, since most people won't belive you even if you say you have no access. it would probably be best to just delete it once the session is done, and that would be enough security for most people. if you want it to be 100% secure then just ask them for the data needed every time they was to make a request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not explicitly mentioned, the "telethon" tag was added to the question, so I will assume this is the library you intended to use.

Telethon's v1 default storage is indeed an SQLite database, but it does not need to be. It's merely a good default.

A session primarily exists to persist the authorization key used to encrypt communication with Telegram. Once you login, Telegram remembers that this authorization key is logged-in, and does not need to login in the future until logged out.

As soon as you have an logged-in authorization key, you have full access to the account. This means it's never safe for a server to have it at all, if you don't want to risk all of them being leaked.

The only choice is to communicate with Telegram exclusively on the client-side.

Python on the web may be doable, but is probably not the best idea.

However, there are JavaScript libraries such as [gram-js](https://github.com/gram-js/gramjs) that were inspired by Telethon and may help you out.

Comment: Hi, yes im using Telethon! (thanks for maintaining it). I agree with what you have pointed out, will take it into account. gramjs you mentioned was cool! However for this scenario I would have to persist the session. I would have to fall back to allowing the user to terminate the session whenever they want. Thanks @Lonami !

Answer (score 0):

No, the architecture you're currently using isn't ideal for secure data storage on your server. Even if you encrypt the session file, it must be decrypted server-side to make Telegram API calls, thereby potentially exposing user data. Storing this data in the user's browser could be an alternative, but it would prevent you from taking any actions on the user's behalf unless they are actively logged in. To answer your question better way, you need to clearly specify what your app want to achieve with the Telegram session and based on that, you might come with more secure approach.

Comment: Telegram session uses: read new message from a chat when requested by client, and log in log out of telegram session from the webapp. that's all.

I have thought about saving the file on client browser, however from my research, there's only indexeddb and web storage. I assume the former would not be able to keep the sqlite file, and the latter is just a key value pair storage. Any ideas?

Comment: What about end-to-end encryption - the server could just be a pass-through for encrypted data from Telegram. You use JavaScript to do the encryption and decryption client-side, so the server never sees the plaintext data. Or better, you'd implement telegram connectivity as client side only and then send read messages to web app. The point about simply deleting the session after it's over is valid but does not eliminate the risk completely. It only minimizes the window during which data could potentially be compromised. Whatever we come here with will probably be not worth implementing.

Comment: `edit: one more use of the telegram client is to persist after leaving the webapp, so I guess storing client side is out... `

Comment: yep. client side is ruled out by this

Comment: yeap, agreed. It would be overengineering it. Thanks for your help anyways!

Comment: If you got your doubts answered, please accept the answer. thanks